# Cannot bind parameter to argument 'command' because it is null. Powershell

Tags: powershell, start-job

I had a function similar to below code. It receives command and the command arguments. I had to run this command in background and collect the output. But that last statement is bugging me with this error

Error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpre
ssionCommand
+ PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Code:

```
$cmd = 'Get-content'
$Arg = 'path to file'
$sb = "$cmd $Arg -ErrorVariable e -ErrorAction Stop"
invoke-Expression $sb #This printsoutput
$job = Start-job -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression $sb}
wait-job -id $job.Id
$job | Receive-job #this should print output but throwing error
```

I am pretty sure last line is the one throwing the error.

Comment: *But I don't know the root cause.* `$sb` is not exists inside of the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that you are not actually giving `Invoke-Expression` a command.

Whenever you create a new context ( in this case, a job ) you loose your access to the parent session's environment. In your case `$sb` is currently null.

The way that you manage this is to pass the values as arguments via the `-ArgumentList` parameter of `Start-Job`:

```
start-job -ScriptBlock {} -ArgumentList
```

In order to facilitate handing $sb to the ScriptBlock you would do this:

```
$sb = "$cmd $Arg -ErrorVariable e -ErrorAction Stop"
$job = start-job -ScriptBlock { Param([string]$sb)
    Invoke-Expression $sb
} -ArgumentList $sb
```

This can be confusing so this is the same code written with more friendly names:

```
$OuterSB = "$cmd $Arg -ErrorVariable e -ErrorAction Stop"
$job = start-job -ScriptBlock { Param([string]$InnerSB)
    Invoke-Expression $InnerSB
} -ArgumentList $OuterSB
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. This does solved the issue.
But why did the powershell is throwing error at the last line when the error is from Invoke-Expression?

Comment: You are placing your command inside a script block when you assign `start-job` to `$job`. This starts the process in the background. On your last line you are retrieving the output of that job. The error you are seeing is the output of that job.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative to get the `$sb` into the scope of the scriptblock besides `-argumentlist` is to use the `$using:` scope. (PowerShell 3+)

```
$cmd = 'Get-content'
$Arg = 'path to file'
$sb = "$cmd $Arg -ErrorVariable e -ErrorAction Stop"
$job = Start-job -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression $using:sb}
wait-job -id $job.Id
$job | Receive-job
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error but when I run PowerShell using administrator privileges, I don't get this error. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when running command with user without proper authorizations.
This in deed can be related to that.
For example my code:

```
$allParams = @(10, "Some Process")

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $restartProcessRobot -ArgumentList $allParams

<#
@descr
    Function that restarts given proces -DisplayName after given number of seconds.
@param1 Integer number of seconds after which the process should be restarted.
@param2 String  display name of process(es) that must be affected. Wild cards accepted.
#>
$restartServiceAfter = { 
    param($seconds, $processName)
    Start-Sleep $seconds
    Restart-Service -DisplayName $processName -Force
}
```

And user is not authorized to restart services.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when there was a typo in the name of my conda environment: it was `env2` instead of `env3`.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\mc\Documents\GitHub> conda activate env3

EnvironmentNameNotFound: Could not find conda environment: env3
You can list all discoverable environments with `conda info --envs`.


Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is an empty string.
At C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:107 char:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Invo
   keExpressionCommand

(base) PS C:\Users\mc\Documents\GitHub> conda activate env2
(env2) PS C:\Users\mc\Documents\GitHub>
```